# Need To read through excel sheet in R or python and add columns based on row names

Tags: python, r

I want to read through the names of the Rows and create a new column with just the final element i.e. "C", "c2"

```
Mo2GeC  302.737

Mo2PC   300.034

Mo2AsC  278.077

Sc3AlC2 126.561

Sc3GaC2 121.334

Sc3InC2 163.455
```

Comment: What is "final element"?

Comment: the last one or two portions of the string C= carbon, C2=carbon 2

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `tidyverse` in R.

`str_sub` is to subset the string based on the index. `str_replace` is to replace the unwanted string with "".

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(new = str_sub(V1, -2, -1),
         new = str_replace(new, "^[^C]", ""))

dat2
#        V1      V2 new
# 1  Mo2GeC 302.737   C
# 2   Mo2PC 300.034   C
# 3  Mo2AsC 278.077   C
# 4 Sc3AlC2 126.561  C2
# 5 Sc3GaC2 121.334  C2
# 6 Sc3InC2 163.455  C2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Mo2GeC  302.737

                  Mo2PC   300.034

                  Mo2AsC  278.077

                  Sc3AlC2 126.561

                  Sc3GaC2 121.334

                  Sc3InC2 163.455",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python (with pandas, if column one is 'name' and new column to be called 'final'), you could use regex to get the last element:

```
import re
d = {'name': ['Mo2GeC','Mo2PC','Mo2AsC','Sc3AlC2'], 'num':[302.737,300.034,278.077,126.561]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['final'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*", x)[-1])
```

result:

```
      name      num final
0   Mo2GeC  302.737     C
1    Mo2PC  300.034     C
2   Mo2AsC  278.077     C
3  Sc3AlC2  126.561    C2
```